# Microsoft 365 Forms prefilled form with unique URL

Tags: ms-forms

I thought I had done this in the past, but is there a way utilizing Microsoft Forms that I can have a survey pre-filled out for at least one question and share that unique link to that survey?

Context is I'm sending out feedback requests on some direct reports and I'd like a unique link for each direct report to make the survey a little easier for the people filling it out. My company switched from Google to Microsoft in 2021 and I thought I had done this since then, but maybe it was only a Google feature.